# Como usar paginate do laravel com uma query manual?

Tags: laravel, paginação, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma `query` manual na minha model, e quero retornar para a `view` do `blade` o resultado dessa consulta com paginação. Existe alguma forma?

> Model

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'title',
        'description',
        'created_at',
        'priority',
        'g',
        'u',
        't',
        'provide_closure',
        'situation',
        'solution',
        'closing_date',
        'client_id',
        'ticket_type_id',
        'ticket_category_id',
        'equipment_id',
        'user_id'
    ];

    protected $table = 'ticket';

    public function getClosed()
    {
        return $this->where('situation', '=', 4)->orderBy('priority', 'desc')->get();
     }

}
```

> Controller

```
public function getClosed()
{
    $ticket = new Ticket();
    $data = $ticket->getClosed(); //Preciso paginar isso.
    $progress = $this->getProgress();
    return view('ticket.index', ['data' => $data, 'progress' => $progress]);
}
```

Comment: Já tentou trocar o `get()` por `paginate()` no  método `getClosed()` do seu model?

Comment: @AmandaLima funcionou ^^. Muito obrigado, pode formular a resposta para que eu a aceite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu model, troque o `get()` por `paginate()` no return do método `getClosed()`.

*Ficará assim:*

```
public function getClosed()
{
   return $this->where('situation', '=', 4)->orderBy('priority', 'desc')->paginate(15);
}
```

Comment: perfeito +1 ...